# Does r::find in redbean support more than one search field

Tags: php, redbean

I am trying to search by more than one criteria. I have searched Redbean's site for the correct syntax but all they offer is examples using only one search criteria.

```
$match = R::find('tuba', ' displayType = ? ', [ '$displayType' ]);
```

I am trying to also search by inventoryNUM. Ive tried executing this code but to no avail.

```
$match = R::find('tuba', ' displayType = ? , inventoryNUM = ? ', [ '$displayType' , '$inventoryNUM' ]);
```

Is this the correct syntax? Does R::find even support more than one search criteria?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the following:

`$match = R::find( 'tuba', ' displayType = ? AND inventoryNUM = ? ', [$displayType, $inventory]);`

Just remember that everything in the 2nd parameter is `SQL query to find the desired bean, starting right after WHERE clause`.  Also you can either use the question mark notation or the slot-notation (:keyname).

The following query is equivalent to the one above:

`$match = R::find( 'tuba', ' displayType = :displayType AND inventoryNUM = :inventoryNUM ', [':displayType' => $displayType, '':inventoryNUM' => $inventory]);`